# Program Looping if strong password is met a second time

Tags: python

I am having a weird problem, I am not sure why this is happening. I find it hard to explain but here it goes. My program is working fine, checking length and even the strength. My problem is if the input fails a first time in any way, then is re-entered and is a correct length and strength it will re-ask for password input. I was thinking it was because of the last like `passwordbegin()` but then if I removed it the program obviously would not run. Can anyone maybe give me a hint or explain to me why this is happening? Thanks in advance!

```
def passwordbegin():      
        Upper = 0 
        Lower = 0  
        Number = 0 
        pass_check = True 
        while pass_check is True:  
            passw = raw_input("Please enter your password. It must be between 6 and 12 characters long and contain atleast capital letter, lowercase letter and number.")

            if len(passw) < 6: 
                print("Your password is too short, it must be at least 6 characters long")  
            elif len(passw) > 12:
                print("Your password is too long, it must be no more than 12 characters long")  
            else:
                print("Your password is the correct length.")   
                pass_check = False  

            if pass_check is False:  
                for char in passw:  
                    if char.isupper():  
                        Upper =+ 1  
                    if char.islower():
                        Lower =+ 1  
                    if char.isdigit():
                        Number =+ 1   
            Password_Strength = Number + Lower + Upper          
            if Password_Strength == 1:
                print("Your password is weak, trying adding Numbers or Upper and Lowercase Letters") 
                raw_input("Press enter to restart the program")  
                while True:
                    passwordbegin() 
            if Password_Strength == 2:  
                print("Your password is medium strength, try adding Upper or Lowercase Letters and Numbers") 
                raw_input("Press enter to restart the program")
                while True:
                    passwordbegin()
            elif Password_Strength == 3:
                print("Your password is strong and secure, thank you for entering!")
    passwordbegin()
```

Comment: Please explain the reasoning for having `passwordbegin` call itself  from inside a nested loop, where the innermost loop is written to explicitly be an infinite one.

Comment: Sorry, I am not the best at Python, I am only a beginner. I have done this so if the Password_Strength == 1 then press enter to restart the function

Answer (score 1):

don't use `while pass_check is True:` it doesn't do what you think it does.

You should use `while pass_check == True` or even better `while pass_check:

The main issue is that you are calling your function again, rather than just letting it loop.

in stead of calling `passwordbegin()` - use a `continue` (to go back to the start of the loop), and you don't need the continue in `while True:` loops.

Comment: The problem still persists after the change

Comment: have you replace all of your calls to `passwordbegin` ?

Comment: and did you get rid of those `while True:` loops ?

Comment: No i did not! Sorry i am not the best! Thanks for the quick replies

Comment: Sure it does! Thanks for the help. Really appreciate it.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 : You need 15 points to upvote, and I suspect the OP is "not the best" at understanding how SO works, and doesn't know how to accept an answer.